# I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException while executing java file transfer program using jcraft-Jsch api but working with other API

Tags: java, sftp, ftp-client

I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException while executing java file transfer program using jcraft-Jsch api but working with other API like apache with same connection details.

I am able to connect to FTP server using any FTP client software.

1. Program using Jsch API

   Dependency used:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
       <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
       <version>0.1.55</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Program using Jsch:

   ```
   JSch jsch = new JSch();
   jsch.setKnownHosts("/Users/test/.ssh/known_hosts");
   Session jschSession = jsch.getSession("username", "remoteHost","port");
   jschSession.setPassword("password");
   jschSession.connect();  //Failing here and  connection is not established
   ChannelSftp  channelSftp=jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
   channelSftp.connect();

   String localFile = "src/main/resources/sample.txt";
   String remoteDir = "remote_sftp_test/";

   channelSftp.put(localFile, remoteDir + "jschFile.txt");

   channelSftp.exit();
   ```

   Note: I am able to connect to FTP server using any client software but not with above program
2. Program using apache-net

   Working program with same connection details using apache net api:

   Dependency used:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
       <version>3.6</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   Program:

   ```
   String host="XXXXX";
   int port = 21;
   String user = "username";
   String pass = "pwd";

   FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
   try {
       ftpClient.connect(server, port);
       ftpClient.login(user, pass);
       ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
       ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
       // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
       File firstLocalFile = new File("C://internal/test.pdf");
       String firstRemoteFile = "test.pdf";
       InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);
       System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
       boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
       inputStream.close();
       if (done) {
           System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
       }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally {
       try {
           if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
               ftpClient.logout();
               ftpClient.disconnect();
           }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Post the stack trace in your question. Always.

Comment: I don't see where you use sftp in the 2nd example, only in the first. Please [edit] your question and make the code a [mcve] for both. Can  you use sftp on the shell? See also [ask].

Comment: If these two pieces of mutually incompatble code are talking to the same server and port one of them is bound to fail, as they are speaking different protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSch code uses SFTP. Your Apache Commons Net code uses FTP.

Those are two completely different and incompatible protocols.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the reply. But getting error while connecting and we are opening channel after connection. Even i tried adding FTP instead of SFTP but no luck.

Comment: We know that you are getting an error while connecting – BEcause your server most probably does not support SFTP. + What does it mean *"Even i tried adding FTP instead of SFTP but no luck"* – You have claimed that your FTP code works.